# Visual Studio Code doesn't recognize TypeScript module from `node_modules`

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Cloned the [`tslint` repository](https://github.com/palantir/tslint), did `npm install` and `grunt`, as told in the README, and opened the folder in Visual Studio Code (0.9.1).  Looking at any `.ts` file - `src/rules/typedefRule.ts`, say - gives TypeScript errors on `require "typescript"`: `Cannot find module 'typescript'.`

The `typescript` module is in the `node_modules` folder, but VSC doesn't seem to know about that.  How do I tell it to?

Comment: Have you run npm install -g typescript?

Comment: Yes.  I should also add that I'm on OSX 10.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The typescript module is in the node_modules folder, but VSC doesn't seem to know about that. How do I tell it to?

Two things:

- The *current* version of typescript that `vscode` uses doesn't support `typings` lookup. You will need to update it to latest (typescript nightly) using the `tssdk` setting
- The *current* typescript used by tslint (`1.6.2`) doesn't have `typings` field. You need to update tslint as well (a much bigger task).

Suggestion: Follow the other steps in readme and use THEIR definition file : https://github.com/palantir/tslint#custom-rules

Comment: I'm having (what I believe to be) a similar issue whereby VS (0.9.1) code doesn't recognise a module in  `node_modules/` and thus I get error highlighting and no Intellisense for the imported module. I've updated `vscode`'s `tssdk` setting to `path/to/typescript_1.6.2/lib/` doesn't seem stop the errors relating to module imports or Intellisense for those imported modules. (Note that after the `tssdk` changes Intellisense within the file still works.) Could you perhaps elaborate on your first bullet point? Does TS 1.6.2 support `typings` lookup?